# Perzeptron algorithm - code error - Python 3

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-3.6

I am working through the German book "Machine Learning with Python" by Sebastian Rashka.
I am using anaconda and spyder (including ipython console) on a windows machine.

In chapter 3 he is relying to an algorithm based on the "Perzeptron model".
Following the authors instruction, the code should be as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print('Korrektklassifizierungsrate: %.2f' % accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
def plot_decision_region(X, y, classifier, resolution=0.02):
    
    # Markierungen und Farben einstellen  
    markers = ('s', 'x', 'o', '^', 'v')
    colors = ('red', 'blue', 'lightgreen', 'gray', 'cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])
    
    #Plotten der Entscheidungsgrenze
    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, \
         resolution), np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), \
                                     xx2.ravel()]).T)
    
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
                  plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha=0.4, cmap=cmap),
                  plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
                  plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())
    
    #Plotten aller Exemplare
    for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
        plt.scatter(x=X[y == cl, 0], y=X[y == cl, 1],
                    alpha=0.8, c=cmap(idx),
                    marker=markers[idx], label=cl)
    
    #Exemplare der Testdatenmenge hervorheben
    if test_idx:
        X_test, y_test = X[test_idx, :], y[test_idx]
        plt.scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c='',
                    alpha=1.0, linewidths=1, marker='o' s=55, label='test set')
        
X_combined_std = np.vstack((X_train_std, X_test_std))
y_combined = np.hstack((y_train, y_test))
plot_decision_regions(X=X_combined_std,
                      y=y_combined,
                      classifier=ppn,
                      test_idx=range(105,150))
plt.xlabel('Länge des Blütenblatts [standardisiert]')
plt.ylabel('Breite des Blütenblatts [standardisiert]')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-e576c1f255dd>", line 19
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha=0.4, cmap=cmap),
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

So, I am not sure what the default is. I would really like to understand the error and would appreciate, if someone could help me out. Could it be, that it has something to do with the equation cmap=cmap ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unindent lines from 19 to 21.

```
Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha=0.4, cmap=cmap),
plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())
```

Comment: Hey Dawit, thank you, that is the intended error, I know but how can I avoid it?

Comment: Why did you indent it? Were the lines below 19 supposed to be arguments? If so you closed the bracket on line 19 and you need comma on line 21 also closing bracket on line 22.

Comment: Hi Dawit,
thank you for answering. 
Why I did that? Because I wasn't aware what "indent" meant ... but thanks to you and leo.org, now I was able to solve it. Thank you. The author has never explained why he is doing indentions or why not and when I have to use them and when not. 
But now, I am going to check some youtube videos to learn more about it :-). Thanks a lot.